# Oracle PL/SQL - String Match and Removal Function

Tags: string, oracle, function, plsql

I have a function that compares values from `STR_A` with `STR_B`, the 'dream' is that any matching characters between `STR_A` and `STR_B` will be removed from `STR_A`.

For example; `STR_A = 'LTD'` and `STR_B = 'LIMITED'` therefore the results will be `null`.

Order is important, so if `STR_A = 'LDT'` and `STR_B = 'LIMITED'` the result will be `'T'`.

Another example; `STR_A = 'AUSTIN'` and `STR_B = 'ADVERTISING'` the result will be `'UT'`

Note; the number of characters in `STR_A` will always be less than or equal to `STR_B`.

Also, a character can only be used once, therefore if `STR_A = 'LLTD'` and `STR_B = 'LIMITED'`, the result will be `'L'`.

The function I have is as follows;

```
create or replace FUNCTION CP_RDN_REMSTR(
  S1 VARCHAR2,
  S2 VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
 LEN INTEGER := NVL(LENGTH(S2),0);
 OUTSTR VARCHAR2(32767) := S1;
 POS INTEGER := 1;
 IND INTEGER := POS;
BEGIN
 FOR I IN 1..LEN
 LOOP
  POS := INSTR(SUBSTR(OUTSTR,POS),SUBSTR(S2,I,1));
  IF POS > 0 THEN
   OUTSTR := SUBSTR(OUTSTR,1,POS-IND)||SUBSTR(OUTSTR,POS+IND);
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
RETURN OUTSTR;
END;
```

However, using the above isn't giving me the desired results;

```
SELECT CP_RDN_REMSTR('LTD','LIMITED') AS STR_A FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CP_RDN_REMSTR('LDT','LIMITED') AS STR_A FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CP_RDN_REMSTR('AUSTIN','ADVERTISING') AS STR_A FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CP_RDN_REMSTR('ADP','ADVANCED') AS STR_A FROM DUAL
```

The results are as follows;

```
('LTD','LIMITED')        = NULL
('LDT','LIMITED')        = 'D'
('AUSTIN','ADVERTISING') = NULL
('ADP','ADVANCED')       = 'P'
```

The expected results are;

```
('LTD','LIMITED')        = NULL
('LDT','LIMITED')        = 'T'
('AUSTIN','ADVERTISING') = 'UT'
('ADP','ADVANCED')       = 'P'
```

As always, many thanks in advance.

Comment: This statement makes no sense: "Order is important, so if STR_A = 'LDT' and STR_B = 'LIMITED' the result will be 'T'." Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I’ll attempt to explain it better;  the reason why the result would be ‘T’ in this case is because after matching ‘D’ (from ‘LDT’), there are no characters left in ‘LIMITED’ to match (with ‘D’ being the final character in the string).

Comment: Interesting question! Making sure I got it right: suppose you are comparing AXD to ADLMPXFPDP - you should return NULL, correct? You need to find A, X and D, in that order, SOMEWHERE In the RHS string; the first occurrence of D can be ignored.

Comment: Also: PL/SQL only? Or are you also interested in a pure SQL solution (which may be a lot faster in real life, if the data is in tables)?

Comment: Correct, Mathguy (although I probably didn’t phrase it particularly well). Regarding approach; I’m easy like a Sunday morning (pure SQL is fine). Thanks

Comment: I was also researching in to text segmentation “thebrownfox” to “the brown fox” but after reading in to it, I concluded it would be very complex (and / or would need the use of a full dictionary). Although someone did write a paper that included code (in C++) that claimed to segment text. Maybe one day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a recursive factored subquery (recursive WITH clause), available since Oracle 11.2. If your Oracle version is older, something similar can be hacked using PL/SQL code.

We inspect the letters from the LHS string, one at a time. We check to see if we can still find a match, using REGEXP_LIKE (and a recursive pattern, starting with NULL). At each step, if a match is found, we expand the pattern; if a match is not found, we expand the UNM string (for "unmatched").

There is no requirement that the LHS be shorter than the RHS, it makes no difference. The solution also handles NULL correctly on either side (I added data to test that as well).

Note the test data created in the first factored subquery - it is for testing only, it is not part of the solution.

```
with
     inputs ( lhs, rhs ) as (
       select 'LTD'   ,'LIMITED'     from dual union all
       select 'LDT'   ,'LIMITED'     from dual union all
       select 'AUSTIN','ADVERTISING' from dual union all
       select 'ADP'   ,'ADVANCED'    from dual union all
       select 'ALPHA' , null         from dual union all
       select null    ,'BETA'        from dual
     ),
     r ( lvl, lhs, rhs, unm, pattrn, next_letter ) as (
       select  1, lhs, rhs, null, null, substr(lhs, 1, 1)
         from  inputs
       union all
       select  lvl + 1, lhs, rhs,
               unm    || case when regexp_like(rhs, pattrn || '.*' || next_letter)
                              then null else next_letter end,
               pattrn || case when regexp_like(rhs, pattrn || '.*' || next_letter)
                              then '.*' || next_letter end,
               substr(lhs, lvl + 1, 1)
         from  r
         where next_letter is not null
     )
     cycle lvl set cycle to 1 default 0
select lhs, rhs, unm
from   r
where  next_letter is null
;
```

**Output** (from the simulated inputs):

```
LHS     RHS          UNM  
------  -----------  -----
        BETA                             
LTD     LIMITED                          
LDT     LIMITED      T                   
ADP     ADVANCED     P                   
ALPHA                ALPHA               
AUSTIN  ADVERTISING  UT
```

**Note**: Here is one way to see what the recursive query does. At the very end of the solution, I just selected the columns and the rows I needed from `r`. Instead, replace those last few lines with

```
select   *
from     r
order by lhs, lvl
;
```

and look at THAT output.

**EDIT**

Fun problem. Here is a solution that should work quite a bit faster than the first version. It uses only standard string functions (INSTR and SUBSTR), which are quite a bit faster than regular expressions. Moreover, working from left to right, letters that have already been inspected don't need to be carried forward (resulting in longer and more complex matching pattern); instead, it is possible to check just one letter at a time, and to chop off initial segments from the RHS string at each step, making each search shorter.

```
with
     inputs ( lhs, rhs ) as (
       select 'LTD'   ,'LIMITED'     from dual union all
       select 'LDT'   ,'LIMITED'     from dual union all
       select 'AUSTIN','ADVERTISING' from dual union all
       select 'ADP'   ,'ADVANCED'    from dual union all
       select 'ALPHA' , null         from dual union all
       select null    ,'BETA'        from dual
     ),
     r ( lhs, rhs, next_letter, unm, new_lhs, new_rhs ) as (
       select  lhs, rhs, substr(lhs, 1, 1), null, lhs, rhs
         from  inputs
       union all
       select  lhs, rhs, substr(new_lhs, 2, 1),
               unm || case when nvl(instr(new_rhs, next_letter), 0) = 0 
                           then next_letter end,
               substr(new_lhs, 2),
               substr(new_rhs, nvl(instr(new_rhs, next_letter), 0) + 1) 
         from  r
         where next_letter is not null
    )
    cycle new_lhs set cycle to 1 default 0
select lhs, rhs, unm
from   r
where  next_letter is null
;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Mathguy! I’ll test it shortly. As always, much appreciated.

Comment: @MAndrews - I am adding a note on how you can "see" the recursive results in their totality (to understand how this works).

Comment: @MAndrews - So, what happened? How is it that the incorrect solution is now marked "Correct"? Did you find any issues with the solution I provided?

Comment: @MAndrews - Arghh...  I see you moved the "Correct" checkmark again. I don't care about being right, or about reputation points; I care about the answer being correct (or not). So, still waiting to hear what happened.

Comment: Sorry, Mathguy; I meant to only give the other answer a ‘thumbs up’ but ironically I’m all thumbs today (I’m logged in via my phone as opposed to desktop and inadvertently pressed the ‘wrong button’. Thanks for the heads-up; I’ve corrected my mistake and to answer your question; no issues - it’s working a treat.

Comment: As with most of my output today, my comment was also riddled with errors... Friday the 13th; I think I’ll go back to bed.

Comment: @MAndrews - I don't know how important performance is in your problem. I liked the challenge. I came up with what I believe is a better solution (based on a better algorithm - not related to "programming", just better logic for solving it). I posted it as an **EDIT** under the original Answer.

Comment: That’s really neat, @Mathguy! Looking forward to testing it later. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment about order being important, it sounds like you want to loop through each character in `S2` and only remove it from `S1` if it's the leading character of `S1`.

The following satisfies your first, second and fourth examples, but causes the third example to not make sense:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CP_RDN_REMSTR (S1 VARCHAR2, S2 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   LEN      INTEGER := NVL (LENGTH (S2), 0);
   OUTSTR   VARCHAR2 (32767) := S1;
   POS      INTEGER := 1;
   IND      INTEGER := POS;
BEGIN
   FOR I IN 1 .. LEN
   LOOP
      POS := 0;
      POS := INSTR (SUBSTR (OUTSTR, POS), SUBSTR (S2, I, 1));

      IF POS = 1 THEN
         OUTSTR := SUBSTR (OUTSTR, 1, POS - IND) || SUBSTR (OUTSTR, POS + IND);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN OUTSTR;
END CP_RDN_REMSTR;
```

Output:

```
('LTD','LIMITED')        = NULL 
('LDT','LIMITED')        = 'T'
('AUSTIN','ADVERTISING') = 'USTIN' 
('ADP','ADVANCED')       = 'P'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer. Regarding the third result; because the match would be A-S-I-N ([A]u[S]t[IN] > [A]dverti[SIN]g), leaving UT. However, your solution may actually satisfy what I need - I’ll run some tests. Many thanks once again, much appreciated.